# How can I use Packages in my source code file .cs without IDE?

Tags: c#

I use csc.exe to compile the source files.
I would like to download and use a package [PhantomJS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PhantomJS/)  locally with
the source file below.
Is it possible to simply use the downloaded package in the source file, compile it with csc.exe it and run it successfuly?

**SourceFile.cs**

```
using System; 

class HelloWorld {
static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 

       Console.WriteLine("Hello World.");
    }
}
```